# Does updating a project through the Gitlab API (not UI) generate an event that a System Hook can catch?

Tags: github, events, gitlab, gitlab-api, github-webhook

I am trying to set up logic based off of events captured by a Gitlab System Hook. In the docs it seems pretty clear that any changes made within the UI will be captured, but what about the GitLab API? Say I update some merge_request rules with a POST request to the GitLab API, will that change trigger an event that the System Hook can catch?